# Dynamically change datetime format of xAxis Tick Label in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to change datetime format of the X Axis Tick Label between `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` and `MM/dd/yyyy` according to selection by the user. 
How can i achieve this using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution, just made the tickInterval dynamic with the following code(ASP.NET)

```
tickInterval : <%=IsHourly?1:24 %> * 3600 * 1000,
```

Used the same logic to change the tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

```
xAxis : {
            type : 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth : 1,
            gridLineColor : '#F2F2F2',
            lineColor : '#FF0000',
            tickInterval : 3600 * 1000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                second : '%H:%M',
                minute : '%H:%M',
                hour : '%H:%M',
                day : '%e',
                week : '%e',
                month : '%e',
                year : '%e'
            }
        },
```

See the **dateTimeLabelFormats** Option, you can use that to change your x Axis tick label.

Let me know in case you need more clarity.!

**EDIT :**

More API reference can be found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats) on Highcharts' site.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/)

**EDIT 2 :** Ok so if you need to change it dynamically
First save the format you need as `String` based on whatever calculation do.
Something like `var labelFormat = '%H:%M'` etc.
Then in when you render chart put `dateTimeLabelFormats` as following with other required options.

```
dateTimeLabelFormats : { labelFormat }
```

And then call `redraw()` method, and you're done.

**Please Note :** I haven't tested this code.

Comment: I need to do it dynamically. The format will be chosen according to the kind of display preferred by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am way too late but if you are looking for a pure JavaScript implementation this might work:

```
tooltip:{formatter:function(){
            const selectedFormat = document.getElementById("dateFormat").value;
            const finalDate = Highcharts.dateFormat(selectedFormat, this.x);
            return finalDate;
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/527moaLs/

You can find the rest of the solution by yourself, I suppose